# Run pig job as a different user

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

So here is a situation, I have a hadoop cluster that is not configured with Kerberos security and a workstation.  The Hadoop cluster runs Cloudera CDH3 distribution.  The data on the cluster all stored under 'hdfs' user.

The workstation is either linux or macos workstation that runs a complicated piece of software that embeds a PIG client.  The PIG client connects to the cluster to run analytics jobs.

Here is a problem.  The user accounts on the cluster and on the workstation are different, all data in the hadoop cluster is stored under 'hdfs' home directory user the workstation has completely set of user accounts.  Is it possible to tell PIG to execute the job under a different user account. Currently pig attempts to execute job with account of the user who is current logged into the workstation.  The job actually runs but it is not able to access the data because scripts use paths relative to HDFS user home directory.

I understand that when security is not configured for the cluster the user name is simply passed with the job configuration .XML,  but for some reason I can't figure out how to force username I need into that XML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass user via properties. Security subsystem is more complicated, then simply passing username. You have four possible solutions:

1. Disable security at all (why it ever needed, if all data stored under 'root' account?)
2. Create hdfs user on local workstation and run software under sudo -u hdfs
3. Create local workstation user on hadoop cluster, create group for that user and add rigths to read data by this group to files.
4. Don't store files under 'hdfs' and create similar users on workstation and hadoop cluster.

I think preferable way in your case is 1. But if it is not possible, 4 is more appreciated.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I have to go with option 1. Things are more complicated that I explained,  the workstation is actualy a set of different workstations that runs have their own users, but they all need to access the same data on the cluster and it has to be in their home directory.  Don't ask why I know it is silly, but it is just how things are.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set "HADOOP_USER_NAME" environment variable.
More details can be found in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041253/set-hadoop-system-user-for-client-embedded-in-java-webapp).

Comment: This answer actually addresses the problem and is much more suitable, than the accepted one. Especially when it comes to testing and developing.