# M/R job submission failing with error: Could not find Yarn tags property > (mapreduce.job.tags)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I am getting the following exception when running a map/reduce job. We submit map/reduce jobs through oozie.

> Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class
>   [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], main() threw exception,
>   Could not find Yarn tags property (mapreduce.job.tags)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find Yarn tags property
>   (mapreduce.job.tags)  at
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMainHadoopUtils.getChildYarnJobs(LauncherMainHadoopUtils.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMainHadoopUtils.killChildYarnJobs(LauncherMainHadoopUtils.java:88)
>     at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:46)    at
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:46)
>     at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:38)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:228)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:378)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:296)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:224)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745

I did a google search, and found the following SO post: [Hadoop MapReduce job starts but can not find Map class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661978/hadoop-mapreduce-job-starts-but-can-not-find-map-class) However the resolution mentioned in this post is not working for me, I cannot see any file permission related errors in the log files.

We are using Cloudera distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade Oozie sharelibs. Follow instructions [in Cloudera's documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_oozie_configure.html). Namely:

`sudo oozie-setup sharelib create -fs FS_URI -locallib /usr/lib/oozie/oozie-sharelib-yarn`

Don't forget to restart Oozie afterwards. This helped us to solve this particular problem after CDH 5.5 upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am reluctant to execute any command that updated shared libs, because I did not set this cluster up, and the person who set it up is on vacation. Also, workflows started failing suddenly, so I am hoping it is something else that is causing this.

Comment: I did what you suggested, and restarted everything. That seemed to fix the problem. Thanks!