# How to impersonate user through coding for hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, apache-storm

We are working on storm and hive integration where strom will write the data HDFS through hive. However, as topology we deployed is run by strom (user created on cluster which runs the storm topology). However the hive do not have the user as storm and we do not want to create it (for certain reasons). It fails with below exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=strom, access=WRITE, inode="/user/tales/table":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
```

User X has created table.
I know this case can be resolved by

http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Hive+User+Impersonation  -Using this we can impersonate user from hive config

OR

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.permissions</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Disables the user authorization.

Are you aware of any way, we can impersonate the user X through java code while writing to Hive table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That MapR post is about a different issue: HiveServer2 *(the JDBC service)* runs queries on behalf of remote clients, that's real client/server impersonation (as in `runAs`).

In your case it's more like faking another identity. Or using an avatar. *[insert your preferred analogy here]* Anyway:

- on a secure cluster you would create a Kerberos ticket for user X
- otherwise `HADOOP_USER_NAME` is the way to go, either as a Java property or an env variable; see [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041253/set-hadoop-system-user-for-client-embedded-in-java-webapp/11062529#11062529) for example

Comment: Thanks for information, though its kind of hack we are setting up the variable for user. Do we have cleaner way to do it as doAs requires the keytab file. I am running them in cluster so dont want to put keytab file on every machine

Comment: *[Back to work, damn]* If you run your Storm instances in a kind of container (YARN mapper, Docker, whatever) you should be able to "auto-download" the keytab file at container creation time. That's the way we run JDBC calls to our kerberized HiveServer2, using Oozie scheduler and YARN.