# Spark Scala : JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping: Error getting groups for XXX: The user name could not be found

Tags: scala, maven, hadoop, apache-spark, hivecontext

I have been connecting to Hive (which is in  cluster) from my local system with spark in scala IDE , finally placed my hive-site.xml properly in Spark/conf folder and in class path and able to connect to metastore but unable to access hive tables.

How to change the user for HiveContext

15/12/22 10:28:42 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: show tables
15/12/22 10:28:43 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
15/12/22 10:28:45 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://Server.com:9083
15/12/22 10:28:46 INFO JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping: **Error** getting groups for XXXX: The user name could not be found.

15/12/22 10:28:46 WARN UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user XXXXX
15/12/22 10:28:46 INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:** org/apache/tez/dag/api/SessionNotRunning
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anonfun$4.apply(HiveContext.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anonfun$4.apply(HiveContext.scala:231)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.x$3$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.x$3(HiveContext.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$1.(HiveContext.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog(HiveContext.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$3.(HiveContext.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.analyzer(HiveContext.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDDLike$class.$init$(SchemaRDDLike.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.(SchemaRDD.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveql(HiveContext.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hql(HiveContext.scala:106)
    at com.Spark.ConnectToHadoop.CountWords$.main(CountWords.scala:50)
    at com.Spark.ConnectToHadoop.CountWords.main(CountWords.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tez.dag.api.SessionNotRunning
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more

Comment: Looks like your Hadoop cluster does not use Kerberos authentication, so the answer is somewhere in that post >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041253/set-hadoop-system-user-for-client-embedded-in-java-webapp/11062529#11062529

Comment: Anyway that will make **no difference** because your Exception has nothing to do with authentication *(which just displays a Warning)*; your `hive-site.xml` clearly invokes TEZ but you did not provide TEZ libraries to Spark Class Path.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Its not just warning , I'm unable to load my hive tables because of the exception , anyway how can I add Tez Libraries (where should I download it) and does that clear my exception ?

Comment: **1.** Spark SQL is supposed to make TEZ *irrelevant*, so just use my answer below and do not use TEZ -- until you understand what you are doing **2.** Again, the exception has no relation to the warning above!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer that has nothing to do with your question, but then, your question has nothing to do with the Exception shown...

In the `hive-site.xml` that you provided to Spark, change property`hive.execution.engine` from "tez" *(requires TEZ run-time)* to default "mr".

Comment: Thanks, that really helped..

But how to run with tez engine  , will spark only  work with 'mr' on Hive??