# service specific users not created in cloudera

Tags: cloudera, oozie

I did not face any porblems while installing cloudera but I just realized that I should have had users like oozie and hdfs created on my centos machine, I guess under /home directory?

But I do not have any such users under home directory and I am not able to login as oozie user through su oozie command. Is it an installation problem or is there some other way to do it?

Now, that I am trying to copy a jar in oozie sharelib folder, it does not allow so through root user and I do not see any other users created here. I did not opt for single user installation either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is a *distributed* system, it is not bound to the *local* users on a specific server.

If you had **Kerberos authentication** enabled, then it's the user in your **local Kerberos ticket** that would matter *(and you would have to cope with some dirty Kerberos administration chores, although Cloudera Manager helps a lot, especially if you use Active Directory as Kerberos back-end)*

On the other hand, **without Kerberos**, then **anyone can impersonate any Hadoop system account or user account**; the rule appears to be...

1. whatever is set in local env. variable `HADOOP_USER_NAME`
2. failing that, whatever is set in Java system prop. `HADOOP_USER_NAME`
3. failing that, your actual Linux (or Windows) user

Reference:

- that [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041253/set-hadoop-system-user-for-client-embedded-in-java-webapp) that you would have found yourself if you had cared to Google a little bit   :-/
- the [Hadoop source code for authentication](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.1/org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation.java?av=f) - search for `HADOOP_USER_NAME` string constant