# How can I avoid potential user impersonation in HDFS NFSGateway?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

There appears to be a security flaw with using HDFS NFSGateway (I am using [HDP 3.1.4](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/release-notes/content/hdp_relnotes.html)) and I'm not sure how to address it (not very familiar with networking or security etc). Here is an example situation:

1. Some user with root access on their own machine is given access to the HDFS via [NFSGateway](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-storage/content/access_hdfs_from_the_nfs_gateway.html) (ie. has it mounted to their machine)
2. They then make a user with same uid that the user they want to impersonate has on the hadoop cluster nodes
3. They `su` to that user and access the user's mounted version of their `hdfs:///user/<username>` folder on thier machine (users they would not necessarily have access to as root on the client machine)

Eg.

```sh
[root@HW006 user]# #Here is a mounted HDFS NFSGateway
[root@HW006 user]# ls -lh /hdpnfs/user/
total 5.0K
drwx------. 3        1008         1004  96 Sep 11 14:53 accumulo
drwxrwx---. 9        1019         1004 288 Sep 11 15:17 ambari-qa
drwxr-xr-x. 3        1018         1006  96 Sep 11 14:54 druid
drwxr-xr-x. 2        1010         1004  64 Sep 11 14:53 hbase
drwxr-xr-x. 2        1000         1004  64 Sep 11 14:52 hive
drwxrwxr-x. 3        1013         1004  96 Sep 11 15:00 oozie
drwxrwxr-x. 2        1009         1004  64 Sep 11 15:07 spark
drwxr-xr-x. 3 testuser001 hdptestusers  96 Sep 12 13:44 testuser001
drwxrwx---. 4        1001         1006 128 Sep 11 14:50 yarn-ats
drwxr-xr-x. 5        1015         1004 160 Sep 11 14:51 zeppelin
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]# # Now I'll make a user to impersonate the oozie user
[root@HW006 user]# useradd --uid 1015 --no-create-home imposteruser
[root@HW006 user]# ls -lh
total 5.0K
drwx------. 3         1008         1004  96 Sep 11 14:53 accumulo
drwxrwx---. 9         1019         1004 288 Sep 11 15:17 ambari-qa
drwxr-xr-x. 3         1018         1006  96 Sep 11 14:54 druid
drwxr-xr-x. 2         1010         1004  64 Sep 11 14:53 hbase
drwxr-xr-x. 2         1000         1004  64 Sep 11 14:52 hive
drwxrwxr-x. 3         1013         1004  96 Sep 11 15:00 oozie
drwxrwxr-x. 2         1009         1004  64 Sep 11 15:07 spark
drwxr-xr-x. 3 testuser001  hdptestusers  96 Sep 12 13:44 testuser001
drwxrwx---. 4         1001         1006 128 Sep 11 14:50 yarn-ats
drwxr-xr-x. 5 imposteruser         1004 160 Sep 11 14:51 zeppelin
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]# # Now lets see if imposteruser is able to write to the hdfs:///user/zeppelin directory
[root@HW006 user]# su imposteruser
bash-4.2$ pwd
/hdpnfs/user
bash-4.2$ cd zeppelin/
bash-4.2$ pwd
/hdpnfs/user/zeppelin
bash-4.2$ ls
conf  notebook  test
bash-4.2$ touch tmp.txt
bash-4.2$ ls -lh
total 1.5K
drwxr-xr-x. 3 imposteruser 1004  96 Sep 12 11:50 conf
drwxr-xr-x. 4 imposteruser 1004 128 Sep 11 14:51 notebook
drwxr-xr-x. 2 imposteruser 1004  64 Sep 11 14:51 test
-rw-r--r--. 1 imposteruser 1004   0 Sep 13 12:12 tmp.txt
bash-4.2$ exit
exit
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]# # Lets go to a cluster node and see how it looks from there
[root@HW006 user]# ssh hw001
root@hw001's password:
[root@HW001 ~]# hadoop fs -ls /user/zeppelin
Found 4 items
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2019-09-12 11:50 /user/zeppelin/conf
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2019-09-11 14:51 /user/zeppelin/notebook
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2019-09-11 14:51 /user/zeppelin/test
-rw-r--r--   3 zeppelin hdfs          0 2019-09-13 12:12 /user/zeppelin/tmp.txt
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]#
[root@HW006 user]# # So you can see that it looks as is the user zeppelin created the tmp.txt file, when really it was the imposteruser on the NFSGateway-accessing server.
```

Is there any recommended / best-practice way to stop this (though still giving users on that client machine NFS access to the HDFS folders they need to access)?

Comment: Looks like your Hadoop cluster does not use Kerberos authentication - which means that _any Linux user on any host_ can impersonate _any Hadoop user_ , without root privileges. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40310388/5162372  Therefore your issue with NFS is kind of minor, after all...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Interesting. In production, I had planned to use SSSD on the cluster nodes to link to our Active Directory profiles to auth users and have them propagate across the cluster. Would this be sufficient instead of using Kerberos (since want to use existing profiles that exist on AD)?

Comment: You are missing the point. SSSD will map AD accounts and groups to local Linux accounts and groups **=> identity management**. Optionally, SSSD will allow AD accounts to log into Linux using their AD password _(using either Kerberos, or plain LDAP auth with SSL encryption)_ **=> optional Linux authentication**. But it won't manage **Hadoop authentication**.

Comment: By default, Hadoop **authentication** is purely declarative i.e. _"my name is Spiderman, trust me"_ with no control whatsoever. You can switch to Kerberos authentication, then your client will use custom Hadoop libs that override the Java implementation of Kerberos, because that implementation is JDK-specific and lame and brittle, cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html And that will work on Windows, too (even though there is no official Apache build, the Hadoop code base can be compiled for Windows).

Comment: By default, Hadoop **authorization** will map the Hadoop account to the local account to get its local groups, and map these groups to HDFS groups. That's where SSSD comes into play.

Comment: Security is something that must be taken seriously. And it's NOT trivial. Recomended readings: https://2017.berlinbuzzwords.de/17/session/building-fence-around-your-hadoop-environments  and of course https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/  (with some visuals in https://www.slideshare.net/steve_l/hadoop-and-kerberos-the-madness-beyond-the-gate-january-2016-edition)