# Not able to write data in Hive using sparksql

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am loading Data from one Hive table to another using spark Sql.  I've created sparksession with enableHiveSupport and I'm able to create table in hive using sparksql, but when I'm loading data from one hive table to another hive table using sparksql I'm getting permission issue:

> Permission  denied: user=anonymous,access=WRITE, path="hivepath".

I am running this using spark user but not able to understand why its taking anonymous as user instead of spark.  Can anyone suggest how should I resolve this issue?

I'm using below code.

```
    sparksession.sql("insert overwrite into table dbname.tablename" select * from dbname.tablename").
```

Comment: why do you have three `"` in your query?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spark, you need to set username in your spark context.

```
  System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME","newUserName")
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("SparkSessionApp")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  println(spark.sparkContext.sparkUser)
```

Comment: when I'm Executing above command am getting username as spark but while executing  sparksession.sql("insert overwrite into table dbname.tablename" select * from dbname.tablename"). getting same anonymous user.

Comment: You're going to need to paste all of your code and not just that one command

Answer (score 0):

To validate with which user you are running, 
run below command: -

```
    sc.sparkUser
```

It will show you the current user and then 
you can try setting new user as per the below code

And in scala, you can set the username by

```
    System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME","newUserName")
```

Comment: Tried still getting same issue

Comment: What is the output of sc.sparkUser

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you may try this for ananymous user

```
root@host:~# su - hdfs
hdfs@host:~$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/anonymous
hdfs@host:~$ hadoop fs -chown anonymous /user/anonymous
```

In general

export `HADOOP_USER_NAME=youruser` before `spark-submit` will work.
along with spark-submit configuration like below.

`--conf "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME=${HADDOP_USER_NAME}" \`

alternatively you can try using 
`sudo -su username spark-submit --class` your class

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301891/spark-submit-to-yarn-as-a-another-user)

> ***Note*** :  This user name setting should be part of your initial
>   cluster setup ideally if its done then no need to do all these above 
>   and its seemless.

***I personally dont prefer user name hard coding in the code it should be from outside the spark job.***

Comment: was this answer useful ?